# Auto publish to Facebook pages stopped working after moving domains

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

we've been able to autopublish to our Facebook pages (as the page itself ), but after moving to another domain, we keep getting the error:

"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

I originally followed this guide: http://www.devhour.net/automatically-post-page-using-php-facebook-sdk/  to create the Facebook app and set permissions. However..it seems it's a bit outdated in terms of the interface of the new developer console in Facebook..so I can't seem to find where to add my new domain, if it is needed? I'm somewhat clueless of what to do to solve this..so I hope some of you may help to point me in the right direction :/

The publishing method I'm using (if of any use to you) is:

```
public function publish( $data = NULL ){        

if( !$data ) return false;

require_once "Facebook/autoload.php";
require_once "Facebook/Facebook.php";

        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook(

        array(
              'app_id' => $this->app_id,
              'app_secret' =>  $this->app_secret,
              'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
            )
        );

        if( !$data['access_token'] )$data['access_token'] = $this->get_page_token();



    try {

     $response = $fb->post('/' . $this->facebook_page_id . '/feed', $data );

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

        $this->set_error( $e->getMessage() );

        return $e->getMessage();

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

      $this->set_error( $e->getMessage() );

      return $e->getMessage();

    }


}
```

Comment: To add your new domain : 
Go to your facebook app dashboard => settings => basic => app domain

Comment: Thanks for your reply @YoucefMoulahoum.  I tried adding it and got the following error:  "App domains must match the domain of the Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab Url. Please correct these domains:.."

The app is using Facebook login to be able to publish to the pages. I've checked the "facebook-login" product section of the app...and the same domain is setup in "Valid OAuth redirect URI's".

Comment: can you show me the old and the new URL ?

Comment: Due to my client I can't post the url..but..the original url was in this format:

http://clientname.wpengine.com  <--- this was used when creating the facebook application 

Now, the site has been moved to the following structure:

http://clientname.no

All the guides I'ved tried to follow shows the old developer console..so I can't seem to get my head around how to change the needed fields in the new one :/ @YoucefMoulahoum

Comment: You must also change "site url" , the domain must be same on the site url

Comment: @YoucefMoulahoum : I've added a platform = website and set the SITE url here to the same as app domain..now i'm able to save the app domain..but I still get the same error when trying to publish:  "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" :(